# Quickbase Calendar Report - Colorize bar

Tags: jquery, css, quickbase

In the quickbase calendar report - highlight a blue bar for the length of time which is the .itme class.  What I am hoping to do is to change the .itme class to the exact same style except a different color.  Currently I am able to change my class as necessary but I can't upload a css color style to support my new class.  Please see my latest in the code.

```
If(IsNull([Task Name])," ", [Task Name]="Vacation", "<img qbu=\"module\" src=\"/i/clear2x2.gif\" onload=\"javascript: var my_css_class = { backgroundColor : 'red', color : '#fff' };$('.itme').attr('class','my_css_class');\">Apple")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `class` attribute expects a class name that is defined in `<style></style>` tags so passing the definition directly is going to cause some kind of error.  You could try appending a new set of style tags to the document with your class defined like:

```
<style>.my_css_class{background-color:red;color:#fff}</style>
```

I don't think that will work in this instance because the existing `.itme` class has color styling as part of it and I'm not sure how the browser resolves conflicting classes.  You probably don't want to replace `.itme` entirely because it has a lot of other styling information like size and borders.  Instead, I suggest you insert your styling directly in the `style` attribute because it will supersede the class where they conflict.  Try something like this:

```
If(IsNull([Task Name])," ", [Task Name]="Vacation", "<img qbu=\"module\" src=\"/i/clear2x2.gif\" onload=\"javascript: $('.itme').attr('style','background-color:red;color:#fff');\">Apple")
```

I'm not sure what "Apple" is doing for you here but I left it in none-the-less.